# Backdoor Roth IRA Maneuver - Multiple T-IRA Accounts

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, roth-ira, roth-conversion

The way I understand the pro-rata rule is that if you have $5K in T-IRA (deductible), open and contribute $5K to a new T-IRA (non-deductible), then decide to convert the latter $5K into Roth IRA, you will owe tax on $2.5K because in this case $2.5K came out of deductible and $2.5K of non-deductible T-IRA.

With that being said I have two question:

1. If I have $5K (T-IRA deductible) with VanGuard and have another $5K (T-IRA deductible) with TRowe.  Am I right to assume that in the eyes of IRS it doesn't matter which organization the T-IRA is in, and if I want to contribute to non-deductible IRA for the purpose of a transfer to Roth, I should take both in consideration, regardless of with which institution I will create a new T-IRA (non-deductible) plan?   Which means I will pay tax on roughly $3333 in this case.
2. Similarly if I have a variable annuity with NWM, is that considered as an T-IRA in this case?

Thank you

Comment: For the purposes of backdoor Roths (as well as other purposes), _all_ your Traditional IRA accounts (no matter where they are held) are considered to be the same. If you make a $5K non-deductible contribution, that $5K$ is included in what is called the _basis_ of your IRA, and when you do a rollover, the roillover amount is _deemed_ to have been taken proportionately from the taxable part and the nontaxable part (basis) no matter which account you withdraw it from.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I wrote the answer before I saw your comment, why didn't you write it as an answer?

Comment: @littleadv I was in a rush to run some errands and besides I did not have an answer for the second question re annuities. So I figured a comment is best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I right to assume that in the eyes of IRS it doesn't matter which
>   organization the T-IRA is in, and if I want to contribute to
>   non-deductible IRA for the purpose of a transfer to Roth, I should
>   take both in consideration, regardless of with which institution I
>   will create a new T-IRA (non-deductible) plan?

Yes. It doesn't matter how many accounts across how many custodians you have, it all goes into one single aggregate that is used for the taxable portion calculation.

> Similarly if I have a variable annuity with NWM, is that considered as an T-IRA in this case

If it is purchased under IRA then yes.